# Power plans doesn't show up even with power shell

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 Enterprise and I am on the latest update (10.0.18363 build 18363). I am logged in to my system using an Azure AD user as an administrator.

The problem is that I cannot see/change my power options to anything other than balanced.

[image]

I tried getting my curret power plans  But it just returned Balanced

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> gwmi -NS root\cimv2\power -Class win32_PowerPlan | select ElementName, IsActive | ft -a

ElementName IsActive
----------- --------
Balanced        True
```

OR

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> powercfg -l

Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced) *
```

I tried adding the plan but it did not do anything without failing

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> powercfg -duplicatescheme 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
Power Scheme GUID: 68747735-09b5-4ff5-90f3-d3aa768c9557  (High performance)
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> powercfg -l

Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
```

I can see that My user has admin rights (I also ran the PowerShell commands as admin)
[image]

Comment: When I made that comment you had gone to the effort to submit a comment that indicated you had solved your answer.  The entire point of the comment was to indicate that, you should not submit solutions to your own question, as a comment due to the fact that commentary is temporary.  You are never required to accept an answer, so being unable to accept an answer, isn't justification to not submit an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me in the end was Change Registry settings

- Right click Start Select Run Type regedit and press enter to open the
- registry editor Go to the folder:
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power On the
- right, check one of the keys called CsEnabled Click on that key
- Change the value from 1 to 0 Restart your computer